# Numbers of the form $19000\cdot\cdot\cdot001$

Tags: number-theory

Consider the numbers of the form:

> $19000\cdot\cdot\cdot001$.

Some of them are semi-prime with one factor of the form $2^n-1$.

So for example:

$19\cdot10^{49}+1=127\cdot1496062992125984251968503937007874015748031496063$

Is there a particular mathematical reason why the second factor starts with $149606$ and ends with the same digits $149606$ plus the final $3$?. Is there some connection with the fact that $149606$ is a multiple of $127$?

Second question: are there infinitely many $19*10^k+1$ which are semi-primes with one factor of the form $2^n-1$?

Comment: It's a bit hard to read out how many zeros there are. You could just set $N=19\times 10^n +1$ and tell the value of $n$. Thanks.

Comment: Wonderfully 19 is also a prime factor of 149606. Moreover, the 19th prime number is 67 , and 67+67-7=127. Just a number fun! Well question!

Comment: It is because $190000001 = 127\cdot1496063$. This means two things: Firstly, it therefore makes sense that your long number is just under $1496063\cdot 10^{42}$. Secondly, this number $1496063$ is the inverse of $127$ modulo $10^7$, making it the unique 7-digit multiplier of $127$ that results in a number ending in $0000001$, which therefore means your long number must end with those digits too.

Comment: As a similar example: $1400001 = 17\cdot 82353$. Looking at the next number of the form $14\cdot10^n+1$ that is divisible by $17$, we find $14\cdot10^{21}+1 = 17\cdot823529411764705882353$. This ends with $82353$ and starts with almost the same.